# Why won't arraylist store values from multiple client requests?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am sending a string from a client to a server. The server is recieving this string. I convert it to an integer and add it to an arraylist. I want all integers added during the session to be added in the arraylist with the sum of all the values of the arraylist returned to the client. The arrayList however only ever contains the most recent value and doesn't grow. It doesn't store the previous value (ie the arraylist is always of size 1 and sum is always 0+most recent integer as opposed to the sum of all integers). Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong would be great. Thanks

```
//Client Side
public class ConversionClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
    InputStream instream = s.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outstream = s.getOutputStream();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);

    String request = "CONVERT_TO_POUNDS 10\n";
    out.print(request);
    out.flush();
    String response = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Receiving: " + response);   

    request = "CONVERT_TO_POUNDS 50\n";
    out.print(request);
    out.flush();
    response = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Receiving: " + response);

    s.close();
}

} 


//Server Side
 public void handleConversionRequest(String request) {
    String amountStr = in.next();
    int amount = Integer.valueOf(amountStr);
    ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numList.add(amount);
    //System.out.println("Size:" +numList.size());
    System.out.println("Received from client: " + amount);

    if(request.equals("CONVERT_TO_POUNDS")) {
        int sum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<numList.size(); i++){
            sum+=numList.get(i);
        }

        out.println(sum); //server response
        System.out.println("Sending conversion result to client:"+sum);
    }  

    else
        System.err.println("Unknown request!");
    out.flush();
}

 }
```

Comment: You create a new list _each time_ in `handleConversionRequest()`

Comment: @fge seems correct, you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't store the previous value (ie the arraylist is always of size 1)

Which is normal since your `handleConversionRequest()` method creates a new list each time it is called:

```
public void handleConversionRequest(String request) {
    String amountStr = in.next();
    int amount = Integer.valueOf(amountStr);
    ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // <-- HERE
```

Create the list out of this method; what is more, an `ArrayList` is not thread safe, you probably want to use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.